# Как выполнить UPDATE записи после INSERT по Id который возвращает INSERT. PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Необходимо проапдейтить поле в записи, которую только заинсертил, одним запросом.
Пробовал такой вариант:

```
    WITH inserted AS (INSERT INTO table (name, age) VALUES ('user', 18) RETURNING id)
    UPDATE table
    SET user = (SELECT id FROM inserted) || 'user'
    WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM inserted)
    RETURNING id
```

Инсерт отрабатывает, запись добавляется, а апдейт не выполняется как будто id не возвращается.
Пробовал SELECT вместо UPDATE, id возвращается.

Comment: `SET user =`?  Не `SET name =`?

Comment: Что то мне подсказывает, что update не выполнится потому что запись еще не совсем есть. Учитывая, что значение id у вас автоинкремент, значит оно берется из какой то последовательности и тогда вам вообще не нужен update, а явное использование последовательности при вставке id примерно как `nextval('table_id_seq'::regclass)` и currval для вставки в user

Comment: мне тоже что-то такое представлялось, просто хотел понять.

Answer (score 0):

решил вопрос таким образом:

```
    WITH ids AS (SELECT nextval('id_seq') AS id )
    INSERT table (id, name, age, user)
    VALUES ((select id from ids),'user', 18, (select id from ids)||'user')
```